# wicket ListView with TextField in a form

Tags: listview, wicket, textfield

I created a CustomListView, where part of it is a TextField, in which I want to set value of entity Issue:

```
customListView = new ListView<Issue>("fields", issuesModel) {
        @Override
        protected void populateItem(final ListItem<Issue> item) {
        Issue issue = item.getModelObject();
        item.add(new label("name", issue.getName()));
        TextField<String> customTextField = new TextField("customTextField", new PropertyModel<String>(issue, "value"));
         item.add(customTextField);}}
```

Then I have another class, where I have a form in what I add this ListView component, and there are several TextFields for every Issue, where I can write values:

```
IModel<List<Issue>> issuesModel = new CompoundPropertyModel<List<Issue>>(issueValues) {
        @Override
        public List<Issue> getObject() {

            issueValues = new ArrayList<Issue>();
            Issue issue;
            for (BasicIssue basicIssue : basicIssuesList) {
                issue = new Issue();
                issue.setName(basicIssue.getname());
                issueValues.add(issue);
            }
            return issueValues;
        }
    };

customListView = new CustomListView("customListView", issuesModel);
editBasicIssueForm = new Form("form") {
        @Override
        protected void onSubmit() {
        basicIssue.setIssues(issueValues);
 };
editIssuesForm.add(customListView);
```

When I fill all the TextFields for every issue, only the last value is set to the last issue. All the previous Issue values are NULL;
I don't know what the problem is.

My BasicIssue looks like:

```
    @Entity
public class BasicIssue implements Serializable {
private Long id;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Issue> issueList;
}
```

I probebly missed something before, but I use the issuesModel in the customListView to set the values of the issues. And in the form, I need to set this list of issue to the BasicIssue. But the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the problem is in the model. I'd use a `LoadableDetachableModel` instead overriding `CompoundPropertyModel`. And then implement the method `load`.

```
 LoadableDetachableModel issuesModel = new LoadableDetachableModel() {
        protected Object load() {
            ArrayList<Issue> issueValues = new ArrayList<Issue>();
            for (BasicIssue basicIssue : basicIssuesList) {
                Issue issue = new Issue();
                issue.setName(basicIssue.getname());
                issueValues.add(issue);
            }
            return issueValues;
        }
 };
```

Also notice that `issueValues` is in fact a local variable, so there is no need of using a instance variable. The same applies for `issue` inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
        final ListView<mappingListType> listPe = new ListView<mappingListType>("listPe",
            mappingList) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<mappingListType> item) {

            CompoundPropertyModel<mappingListType> cmpdModel = new CompoundPropertyModel<mappingListType>(
                    item.getModelObject());
            item.setModel(cmpdModel);

            textField1 = new TextField<String>("textField1");
            item.add(textField1);               

            textField2 = new TextField<String>("textField2");
            item.add(textField2);


        }

    };
```

This is a simple working example of my application that shows how compoundPropertyModel will
map to the components and display the required information(textField in your case).

Hope it helps you understand your issue as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes it will be working with the CompondPropertyModel, but I missed something before, so my mistake. My code is working too. The BasicIssueList is filled by a Project entity, that is loaded by Ajax at the same page, so the list was empty. I just needed to fill the issueList in the AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior, onUpdate.